# How can I know when a instance is created?

Tags: java, reflection

So I made a simple program that allows you to create instances of a ton of classes.
Now I'm responsible to send the instances created to a server. I really like the classes constructors so I really didn't want to alter them.
How could I listen to this program so that I could know what classes were recently created, i was thinking in using reflection and maybe threads?

Here a shorter example of what i want to accomplish:

```
public class MainApplicaton{

     public static void main(String []args){
        ConnectServer.listenToCreatedInstances().
        new Vase();
        new Dog();
        new House();
     }
}

package stuff.components;
public class Human{
    public Human(){

    }
}

package stuff.components;
public class Dog{
    public Dog(){

    }
}

package stuff.components;
public class House{
    public House(){

    }
}
```

Now my listener thread:

```
   public enum ConnectServer {
        Server;

        public void listenTocreatedIntances(){
            //Something happens here
            Class c ..
            System.out.println("A instance of "+c.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: For the approuch im using now, is to have an Enum and replicate all the constructors on the enum like ConnectServer.createDog(...), but this approach in a long term is not viable.

Comment: using reflection for such purpose smells really fishy, such behaviour seems to be a "business logic" of your application and for this is does need a solution not workarround :) Consider using Factory design pattern to not allow creating objects by constructors at all or using Visitor pattern for providing notification logic when creating the object

Comment: You want to be notified any time any class is instantiated in your entire project? Or is there a set list of classes that you care about? And if you control when the classes are instantiated, why not just handle the logic when they're created?

Comment: Just a certain number of classes lets say the classes in the package stuff.components. I was using the Factory pattern(for what I read just now). But doing ConnectorServer.createDog(2 parms), ConnectorServer.createDog(30 parms), etc, etc. Is just awfull;_; but compared with the visitor pattern, is slighty better.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're interested in object creation or class creation? You can "listen" to class "creation" (loading) events with a custom class loader

Comment: Object creation, I want to know when an instance of a class, let's say Dog(color black, race pitbull) is created. I appreciate all the help guys:3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively easy way to achieve this is by introducing a common parent class, and using the parent class constructor to generate events. Subclass constructors always call the parent class constructor.

```
package stuff.components;
class Component {
    public Component() {
        ConnectServer.Server.onInstanceCreated(this.getClass());
    }
}

class Human extends Component {
    public Human(){
        // implicit call to Component constructor
    }
}

class Dog extends Component{
    public Dog(){
        // implicit call to Component constructor    
    }
}
```

If you want to get events from instance creation without any code modifications whatsoever, you'll have to look further than Java. Your options include:

- aspect oriented programming, for example aspectj: it lets you inject code when specific things happens in a program (for example constructor calls)
- inject code into the subclass constructors at run time using a byte code manipulation library such as ASM

Comment: Is not a bad idea. I kind of like it:3 I kind of end up using the Factory Pattern:3

Answer (score 0):

Another way to answer this question would be to with the FactoryPattern. Every time we register an object we notify the singleton.

```
public class MainApplicaton{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Vase vase = new Vase();
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        House house = new House();
        ConnectServer.listenToCreatedInstances(vase);
        ConnectServer.listenToCreatedInstances(dog);
        ConnectServer.listenToCreatedInstances(house);
     }
}
```

In this Singleton, we would receive the element created and apply the desired behavior.

```
public enum ConnectServer {
        Server;

        public void listenTocreatedIntances(Component component){
            //Something happens here
            System.out.println("A instance of "+component.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
```